# Filter by number of related choices. Django

Tags: django

I have the following view:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "polls/index.html"
    context_object_name = "latest_poll_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five active published polls with at least
        two choices.
        """
        return Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                                   is_active__exact=True,
                                  ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

And I want to publish polls only with two or more choices.
I tried many variants, but it didn't work properly.

How can I implement this cleverly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), is_active__exact=True) \
            .annotate(num_choices=Count('choice')) \
            .filter(num_choices__gte=2) \
            .order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```